# Lost anecdote of a mathematician who gave a presentation without saying a word

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-history

Some weeks ago I saw in a blog post an anecdote of a mathematician who once gave a 'talk' (not really). The special thing was that he came directly to the chalkboard and started doing one computation that took several empty boards. Without saying a word during all the process (in fact all the presentation), when he put the last dot in the computation, the crowd started clapping excitedly.

I sort of remember and I wanted to come back to it to read it with more time, but I lost it. Now I have the doubt. Does anyone know about this anecdote? Who can this mysterious mathematician be?

Thanks!

Comment: If you just google your title, "mathematician who gave a presentation without saying a word", the first result is https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/2105/3301, which has the answer...

Comment: This question is not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the [help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Instead, it is about the history of mathematics, and has an answer on [HSMSE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/).

Comment: @XanderHenderson: The help center lists history of mathematics under the category "There are certain subjects that, **while still on-topic here**, might be better addressed by one of our sister sites:" Linking to HSM is appropriate; closing as off-topic is not.

Comment: @Micah This question has already been asked and answered on HSMSE.  The answer here is essentially identical to the second paragraph of the answer there.  However, the answer here cites an (arguably) inferior reference (Wikipedia, vs Bell's book, along with a critique of Bell's work).  This question is a duplication of effort and does a disservice to the goal of providing a repository of knowledge, in that it marginally increases the noise-to-signal ratio.  Moreover, I see no consensus that closing as off-topic is inappropriate; I would welcome a link to the Meta if you have one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been asked and answered at the historyOfMath.SE site:  https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/2105/3301

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I agree that the other answer (which I upvoted) is superior to the answer here (which I wrote in about five minutes right before going to bed). My disagreement is with your claim that being about the history of mathematics means that it is off-topic on MSE (e.g., see [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23531/are-questions-about-history-on-topic)). If you want to claim that being a duplicate of a question on another site is close-worthy, I won't argue too much, but that doesn't make it *off topic*.

Comment: @Micah As per the help center, this question *might* be on-topic.  As per [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23632/468350) to the meta question you cite, there seems to be a consensus that history questions requiring in-depth knowledge of mathematics are definitely on-topic.  I don't see a consensus regarding questions that require such knowledge.  This question requires no such knowledge, is perfect for HSMSE (and already has a great answer there!), and therefore strikes me as off-topic here.

Comment: That being said, I am not suggesting that this question be deleted.  If it is closed, it provides a useful signpost to the question on HSMSE.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Probably it was about [Frank Nelson Cole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Nelson_Cole)'s factorization of $2^{67}-1$. As Wikipedia says:

> On October 31, 1903, Cole famously made a presentation to a meeting of the American Mathematical Society where he identified the factors of the Mersenne number $2^{67} − 1$, or $M_{67}$. Édouard Lucas had demonstrated in 1876 that $M_{67}$ must have factors (i.e., is not prime), but he was unable to determine what those factors were. During Cole's so-called "lecture", he approached the chalkboard and in complete silence proceeded to calculate the value of $M_{67}$, with the result being $147,573,952,589,676,412,927$. Cole then moved to the other side of the board and wrote $193,707,721 \times 761,838,257,287$, and worked through the tedious calculations by hand. Upon completing the multiplication and demonstrating that the result equaled $M_{67}$, Cole returned to his seat, not having uttered a word during the hour-long presentation. His audience greeted the presentation with a standing ovation. Cole later admitted that finding the factors had taken "three years of Sundays."

[This MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207321/how-did-cole-factor-267-1-in-1903) has a few more mathematical details, as well as a link to [Cole's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183417760) where he described his methods.

Comment: I’m quite skeptical at the idea this demonstration would have taken an hour.   I’m pretty confident I could do it in under half an hour, and I’m not particularly in practice on my long multiplication — whereas Cole was presumably exceptionally practiced and fluent at it, and probably knew some relevant shortcut techniques (though I guess for the sake of the demonstration he might have chosen not to use them), and had also performed these particular calculations multiple times before.

Comment: @Peter: How long would you estimate it takes you to compute $2^{67}-1$, though?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I can write down $2^{20}=1048576$ and $2^7=128$ from memory; then three long multiplications and subtract one.

Comment: @Asaf: I actually just tried finding $2^{67}$, for fun (it’s a slow day here); it took a little under 20 minutes.  I should admit, I cheated slightly — after each multiplication, I checked the result on the computer, and this picked up 2 errors in digits.  So if I was really doing it from scratch purely by hand, say I’d have needed 30–35 minutes, to double-check each multiplication.  But Cole wasn’t doing it from scratch: his notes and/or familiarity with the calculations would have given strictly more help than the computer gave me.

Comment: @Peter: But if you needed to convince everyone in the room, and not just say "oh, trust me on this", then you would have taken the slow route. Right? Otherwise, why not write immediately $p\times q=2^{67}-1$, boom, mic drop. Eh?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: oh, absolutely — you’d need to write the multiplication out in full, or at least only make use of shortcuts that the audience would recognise.  But you wouldn’t need to double-check the calculations for errors, which is the only thing I was using the computer as a shortcut for.

Comment: @Peter: All in all, I think that doing that correctly, accounting for a style of rigor and checking which may vary from person to person (but seems high for someone who spent three years of calculating this), I could imagine this taking an hour.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: Maybe it was slow to write using chalk? Or he was building anticipation?

Comment: @user21820 I think moving the chalk boards and moving around takes some time too. And there are not many shortcuts you can do in multiplication, these are very big numbers, nifty math tricks would likely introduce errors, good old multiplication it is, with double checking after each line. Tss, the youth of today ;J

Comment: @SK19: Yeap; have you seen a student take out a calculator just to compute $2 \times 0.3$? Tsk indeed.

Comment: Didn't someone at around the same time, or maybe in the late 19th century, spend several months manually factoring $2^{4n + 2} + 1$ for some numerical value of n around 20, after which someone pointed out to him that this equals $ 4 . 2^{4n} + 4 . 2^n + 1 -  4 . 2^n $, which is a difference of two squares? ;-)

Comment: re my previous comment, which is no longer editable (?). I just remembered, this was someone called Landry.

Comment: @user21820 Unfortunately children in school, yes. It happens nowadays :8